# An App ID Identifier is not available xCode 8.3.2

Tags: ios, xamarin, mobile, xcode8, ios-app-group

It seems like after updating the xCode(8.3.2), when trying to enable AppGroup to share data between an App and my widget, I get an error:"An App ID with Identitifier 'il.co.xxxx.xxx' is not available.Please enter a differnt string". I've been successfully uploading my app with AppGroup until now. Is it bug in xCode? Do I need now to change my Bundle ID in app to something(com.il.xxx.xxx) and create new provision profiles in order to upload my app?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use Xcode to handle this issue. You have to login in your Xcode with Apple developer account & select automatic option. It will resolve your issue.

Comment: After adding my Apple Id account, in Xcode - >Prefernces->Accounts I have only 2 options: Download All Profiles and Manage Certificates... After clicking Download All Profiles, it doesn't work. Where can I select automatic option? @Gagan_iOS

Comment: ohh sorry for the delay.. Just select general tab for your build settings & follow this link image https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1814/_index.html